# JQuery Ajax send serialized data with extra POST data tagged on

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, serialization, mixed

What I am trying to do with this code is send the order (serialized POST data) plus one more piece of POST data that contains the category/cluster/list ID.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
$("[id^=sortable-]").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    update: function () {

        $("[id^=sortable-]").each(function(index, element) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            var clusterid = $(this).attr("id").replace("sortable-","");
            order.push({cluster: clusterid});
            alert("Order: " + order + "\nCluster: " + cluster); //Just showing update
            $.ajax({
                data: order,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax.php'
            });
        });

    }
 }).disableSelection();
});
```

So basically I'm using multiple lists where the sortable items are interchangeable and I'd like to send the list/cluster ID as well as the order of that list in one data transaction.

However, I do not know the correct syntax to use. I don't really know how to describe what I'm trying to do in technical terms either so not sure what to search for.

Trying to push the data gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object comp[]=1&comp[]=3&comp[]=2&comp[]=4&comp[]=5 has no method 'push'
```

Comment: it's a string, just add to it with the `+=` operator. `order += "&cluster=" + clusterid`

Comment: Perfect! Not sure why I didn't realise that, thank you.